# h1 border around text only

Tags: html, css, border

I have an h1 and I want to put a border around the inner text only. The problem is that the border will naturally fill the entire block which means it covers the length of the page.

I can't turn it into a span because I need the text to be horizontally centered in the middle of the page.

How do I get the border to only wrap the text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply give the element a `display` of `inline-block`, and apply `text-align: center` on the parent:

```css
h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Title</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir! I had text align on the h1 itself but moving it to the parent solved everything!